# Heap vs Stack Memory in java

Tags: java

I have some doubt on Heap and stack memory in java..

1. whether those are memory space or algorithm(procedure) of storing data at run time.
2. Here is the class

   ```
   class HeapStack {

       String str = "test"; // heap memory

       int a = 10;// heap memory

       private void Test(){

           int a = 10;// stack memory

           String str = "test";// heap memory

       }

   }
   ```

am i correct?

Comment: Nope, the pointer `str` in the method is in stack, while the String itself is in the String Pool, the location of which depends on the JVM. Same for the field - pointer in heap, string in string pool. But I have 2 questions to you: 1) Why did you think this is a good Programmers.SE question? 2) Why would you care at all? For most practical uses it doesn't matter whether it's stack or heap.

Comment: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6489#6489

Comment: All objects are will be in heap memory only... that i know very well.. y do u put down vote .. ? need some clarification

Answer (score 3):

You are partially correct. Java works based on pointers, and all variables pointing to objects are pointers (officially called references). The memory for these variables are allocated on stack in case there are defined inside a method or on heap if they are fields. 
The value of data itself is as you defined it: all objects + primitives defined as fields, live on heap while primitives defined inside methods live on stack.

In Java memory allocation is pretty much the same for both stack and heap (as different from C which has a more complex allocation logic for heap): for stack is just push and for heap there is a mechanism called bump the pointer. The big difference is in memory reclaiming; for stack is jut pop while for heap there is the renowned garbage collector.

A more accurate commented class would be:

```
class HeapStack {

    String str /*heap*/ = "test"; // heap memory    
    int a /*heap*/ = 10;// heap memory

    private void Test() {    
        int a /*stack*/ = 10;// stack memory    
        String str /*stack*/ = "test";// heap memory    
    }    
}
```

Comment: It's more complex than that - the string is interned and both instances there are the same object.

Comment: Java can allocate objects on the stack if the compiler can [prove they don't escape the method where they were created](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_analysis), so it's not a sure thing that the instance fields are in the heap.

Comment: @MichaelT Yeah, but it's still in the heap (at least from Java 7).

Comment: @Doval That's pretty cool; didn't knew about it.